# how to check the active class of anchor tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="main_links cf" id="main_link">
    <a class="est_btn" name="single_pane" id="single_pane">
        <span>Single Pane</span>
    </a>
    <a class="est_btn" name="single_with_storm" id="single_with_storm">
        <span>Single with storm</span>
    </a>
    <a class="est_btn" name="double_pane" id="double_pane">
        <span>Double pane</span>
    </a>
    <a class="est_btn" name="high-efficiency-windows" id="high-efficiency-windows">
        <span>High efficiency windows (Low-E)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I want at least one anchor tag of all these should have an active class. Can anyone tell me how it can be done in jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($("#main_link a.active").length!=0){
//element with active class exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
$('.main_links a').each(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('active'))
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```